# What is the Educated badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When selecting which badge to track, there is now one that I haven't seen before:

[image: Educated Badge]

If I select it and click "Go Get It", I get a 404 page. What is this badge for? Is it for the new Documentation part of Stack Overflow and not supposed to be shown yet?

I have seen it on Stack Overflow, Electrical Engineering, and MSE, but is not listed on the "Badges" page for those sites, or here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/273585)

Comment: Also on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], … pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a forthcoming badge for [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing) - it wasn't meant to be enabled just yet.

A build will soon disable this badge until Documentation is live on a given site.  However, if you've chosen to track this badge, you'll need to choose a different one manually, because I'm too lazy<sup>*</sup> to remove your choice :P

Good eyes finding it, though!

<sup>* or too scared to run updates on production databases.</sup>

Comment: This answer duplicated on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320441/educated-badge/320442#320442