# Broken link in Help center section's Documentation

Tags: bug, help-center

I see the [Documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/documentation) link in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking) page.

Clicking on the link it shows the `Page Not Found`. Hope the link is broken.

This happens for all Per site's Help Center - Documentation link.

[image: Broken link in Asking section's Documentation]

Comment: Related bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277958/what-is-the-educated-badge

Comment: Looks like the Documentation link was removed in the Help center pages.